# How do I open a file in such a way that if the file doesn't exist it will be created and opened automatically?

Tags: c, file-io, fopen

Here's how I open a file for writing+ :

```
if( fopen_s( &f, fileName, "w+" ) !=0 ) {
    printf("Open file failed\n");
    return;
}
fprintf_s(f, "content");
```

If the file doesn't exist the open operation fails. What's the right way to `fopen` if I want to create the file automatically if the file doesn't already exist?

EDIT: If the file does exist, I would like fprintf to overwrite the file, not to append to it.

Comment: The mode `w+` is already the right mode: it results in an empty file open for both read and write, whether or not the file already exists. You want to look at the non-zero return value from `fopen_s()` to understand why the call failed. If you don't need random access (and you probably don't) use just `w` for the mode.

Comment: @RBerteig: Thanks. Could you please answer with a code sample in which you show me how to use fopen_s() return value to create a new file in case the file doesn't already exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To overwrite any existing file, use the `creat` call:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int fd = creat (fileName, 0666);  // creates file if not exist, overwrite existing
FILE *f = fdopen (fd, "w");  // optional, if FILE * type desired
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try just doing `fopen(name, "w")`? Also, you should perhaps extend your code to report *what* error is being signalled, using e.g. `perror()`.

#### Note

Incidentally, I would avoid (at least most of) MSVC's `_s` functions despite the warnings. There's very little point in the first place except when:

1. The original function either writes to a passed-in buffer, but does not have a parameter to specify the size of the buffer (e.g. `strcat()`), or
2. The original function was permitted/required to return a pointer to a static buffer (e.g. `strerror()`), which makes

and these functions are non-portable. In short, most of these functions (including `fopon_s()`) are gratuitously non-portable -- using them makes your program less portable but gives no benefit. (The incompatible addendum for C can only make things worse -- unless MS implements it, in which case it might only make things more confusing.)